# pdfx package - incompatibility with bookmark package when using LuaTeX engine

Tags: hyperref, packages, bookmarks, package-options, pdfx

The `pdfx` package is incompatible with the bookmark package, i.e. the resulting file has no bookmarks when the bookmark package is loaded.

I know that the `PDF /X` standard does not allow any bookmarks, but `PDF /A` certainly does. However, the `pdfx` package disables bookmarks with any setting/option.

This looks like a bug with the `pdfx` package, isn't it? Is anyone else able to reproduce this issue?

Here is a `MWE`. Simpy switch between `pdflatex` and `lualatex` and back, to confirm the existence of the bug. The PDF produced by `lualatex` will not have any bookmarks.

```
\PassOptionsToPackage{a-1a}{pdfx}
\PassOptionsToPackage{pdfa}{hyperref}
\PassOptionsToPackage{paper=a4paper, hmarginratio=1:1, vmarginratio=1:1, scale=0.75}{geometry}
\PassOptionsToPackage{all}{hypcap}
\PassOptionsToPackage{nomain, acronym, xindy}{glossaries-extra}
\PassOptionsToPackage{nameinlink}{cleveref}

\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,oneside,openright]{book}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{pdfx}
% \usepackage{hyperref} % comment out if using the 'pdfx' package

\hypersetup{%
    anchorcolor        = black,
    bookmarks          = true,
    bookmarksdepth     = 4,
    bookmarksnumbered  = true,
    bookmarksopen      = true,
    final              = true,
    hyperfootnotes     = false,
    linktocpage        = true,
    pdfborderstyle     = {/S/U/W 1},
    pdfcenterwindow    = true,
    pdfdisplaydoctitle = true,
    pdffitwindow       = true,
    pdfstartview       = {Fit},
    pdftoolbar         = true,
    plainpages         = false,
    unicode            = true,
}%

% ---------- packages to be loaded after hyperref ----------%
\usepackage{hypcap}
\usepackage{glossaries-extra}

% \usepackage{hypdestopt} % seems to have problems with pdfx package?
\usepackage{bookmark} % does not work with pdfx package in lualatex?

\begin{document}

\chapter{First}
\section{First section}
\lipsum[1-2]
\section{Second section}
\lipsum[1-10]
\chapter{Second}
\section{New section}
\lipsum[1-5]
\section{Newer section}
\lipsum[1-8]
\end{document}
```

Comment: In a major project of mine, I do get bookmarks with the PDF/A setting of pdfx. Could you make a MWE?

Comment: @TeXnician  `pdfx` has no problems with the default bookmarks from `hyperref` package, but doesn't seem to handle the `bookmark` package. Can you confirm if you did explicitly load `bookmark` package after `hyperref`?

Comment: I did not load the hyperref package, but the bookmark package. If you load hyperref you should load bookmark afterwards.

Comment: @TeXnician `pdfx` loads `hyperref` package. Yes, I am loading `bookmark` after `pdfx`. I am creating a MWE for this issue now.

Comment: @TeXnician Finally narrowed down the issue. The problem is that this incompatibility happens only when using `lualatex`. The bookmark package works fine in `pdflatex`. I have posted a `MWE`. You may simply change the engine from `pdflatex` to `lualatex` and back, to confirm the existence of thte bug. How can I let the developers know of this bug?

Comment: `texdoc pdfx` shows a document with mail addresses.

Comment: @TeXnician done. sent out an email to the devs

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's a bug in pdfx. It wrongly sets the boolean from ifpdf to false when used with luatex and so confuse following packages.

As a workaround add this:

```
\usepackage{pdfx}
\ifluatex
 \pdftrue
\fi
```

Comment: Thank you. This works great. Upvoted and marked as accepted.